# Converting a Library to WCF web service

Tags: wcf

As the subject line describes, I am in the process of exposing a C# library into a WCF Service. Eventually we want to expose all the functionality, but at present the scope is limited to a subset of the library API. One of the goals of this exercise is also to make sure that the WCF service uses a  Request / Response message exchange pattern. So the interface /API will change as the existing library does not use this pattern

I have started off by implementing the Service Contracts and the Request/Response objects, but when it comes to designing the DataContracts, I am not sure which way to go.
I am split between going back and annotating the existing library classes with DataContract/DataMember attributes VS defining new classes which are like surrogate classes to the existing classes.

Does anyone have any experience with similar task or have any recommendations on which way works best ?  I would like to point out that our team owns the existing library so do have the source code for it. Any pointers or best practices will be helpful

Comment: Remember to consider if you want to use soap or rest or both. This will have impact on your contract designs. Take a look at Microsoft Web API recently released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My recommendation is to use the Adapter pattern, which in this case basically means create brand new DataContracts and ServiceContracts. This will allow everything to vary independently, and will allow you to optimize the WCF stuff for WCF and the API stuff for the API (if that makes sense). The last thing you want is to go down the modification route and find that something just won't map right once you are almost done.

Comment: Thanks Ethan. I actually did just this. I defined brand new classes which define the Service and Data Contracts

Answer (score 2):

Starting from .NET 3.5 SP1 you no longer need to decorate objects that you want to expose with `[DataContract]`/`[DataMember]` attributes. All public properties will be automatically exposed. This being said personally I prefer to use special DTO objects that I expose and decorate with those attributes. I then use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to map between the actual domain models and the objects I want to expose.

Comment: Thanks Darin. I agree with you although I avoided using Automapper as I am not very familiar with the library. I also have concerns using it in my production environment as I don't really know how well this has been tested. I have don't know if Automapper works well with Unity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to continue to use the existing library but want to have control over what you expose as the web service API, I would recommend defining new classes as wrapper(s) around the library.

What I mean to say is don't "convert" the existing library even if you think you're not going to continue to use it in other contexts.  If it has been tested and proven, then take advantage of that fact and wrap around it.

Comment: Thanks Dave. All the 3 answers have the same theme and I am glad I was no different in my approach. Thanks for your feedback